# FAST Search a SharePoint 2010 site which has Forms based authentication

Tags: performance, search, sharepoint-2010

I want to search/crawl a SharePoint 2010 site which has forms based authentication in my local server using FAST Search 2010 server
I have read only access account
**Restrictions**
I don’t have central administrator access on the host site (i.e. the site I want to crawl)
**Approaches I have tried on my local FAST Search 2010 Server**

- Changing default administrator of content crawler
  *Did not work as the user cannot be*
  resolved
- Tried to add the user in Active
  directory
- Created a SSSA service and mapping it
  with the FAST Search Service
- And Yep searched in Google for
  solutions

Can any one point me to the steps for configuring the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just set up a Sharepoint environment with FAST using TMG and Forms based Auth..  What I had to do was create an Alternative Access Mapping for sharepoint using port 8080 (any port will work) and then point FAST to search the sites that way..  This bypasses TMG forms based Auth.. Let me know if that helps..

Comment: Will try that out and give the status in 2-3 days. I have stopped working on that for now

Comment: I am marking this as answer. I do not have time to validate this approach. If it works for any one than please update this thread

Answer (score 0):

So you created a Content SSA on the FS4SP but still wasn't able to get any content?
Did it give any errors/warnings?

Ken

Comment: Yup even after SSA it did not work. "Access denied" error logged